# Se coupent en leur(s) milieu(x)

Tags: grammaire, usage, pluriel

Dans cette si scandée proposition mathématique, est-ce le singulier ou le pluriel qui est de mise?

> Les diagonales d'un parallélogramme se coupent en leur(s) milieu(x).

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse rejeter l'une ou l'autre forme.

Il y a bien en tout deux milieux en jeu d'où :

> ...se coupent en leurs milieux.

Cependant, chaque diagonale n'ayant qu'un seul milieu, le singulier se justifie facilement :

> ...se coupent en leur milieu.

On entend bien plus souvent :

> Les deux présidents se sont serré la main.

que :

> Les deux présidents se sont serré les mains.

On utiliserait bien sûr uniquement le pluriel si les diagonales avaient plus d'un milieu comme on peut dire :

> Les méridiens se rejoignent à leurs extrémités.